# Sequestration of NO and NO2 Gasses into Soil

Tags: climate-change, environmental-protection, nitrogen

The university I'm a student at has been looking into Anaerobic digestion to reduce the environmental impact of the large amount of post-consumer food waste generated on campus. While this project has been a huge success, not only producing hydroponic slurry to grow vegetables for our food pantry, my group has noticed that it's been generating a lot of methane and nitrogen gasses.

While the aforementioned methane can be cleanly burned to power the system, we've had a bit more trouble with the nitrogen, which is a far more potent greenhouse gas than the carbon dioxide generated via burning of methane.

My question is: is there a way to root this gas through soil or some type of substrate that would allow for its quick fixation or sequestration into the soil allowing for the growth of crops? Most things I've been able to find only talk about low background quantities of N2, but not for NO or NO2 (except for their emissions, like from this [OSU](http://pods.dasnr.okstate.edu/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-8686/) study).

If this isn't the place to post this question, please let me know and I'll remove it, but I'm super appreciative for any help as we are a student-run project.